# How Does the Discard Checkout for SharePoint Online Work in User-Created Document Libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Document libraries that are created in addition to the system-generated document library are not equal to the system-generated library. The ribbon is not available when a user opens an additional library, but it is when a user opens the system-generated library. Why is that?

The difference between the system-generated document library and an additional document library manifests when users attempt to discard the check out documents they have checked out.

As the admin, I can see the Discard Checkout option on the More menu option for a given document. When someone has the document checked out, I click the ellipsis (...) for that document to open the menu, select the More option, and select Discard Checkout.

I would expect users with Contribute permissions to be able to discard any document they have checked out, whether or not they have changed anything within the document. That's the way it worked in SharePoint 2010, but we are discovering that this is not the case for SharePoint 365, the online version. This is an issue especially when the user has checked out the document by accident or made no changes to it. SharePoint Online requires the user to open the document, make some change, then choose the Don't Save feature. After that, the system asks if the user wants to discard the checkout.

Why is that?